# Using char **, initializing char ** as array of strings in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, initialization

```
char *c[] = { "str1", "str2", "str3", "str4" }; 
char **c = { "str1", "str2", "str3", "str4" };
```

The first line is valid. The second one isn't. Why?

Comment: they are two different things, an array of char* pointers and a char* pointer to a char* pointer -- not the same thing

Comment: When assigning string literals to a `char *`, do yourself a favour, and specify the storage class: `const char *`... the `const` bit being key here

Comment: Please note that it never makes any sense to have a plain non-const pointer to a string literal - it should be a pointer to const.

Answer (score 5):

The second line is not an array so you can't use array initialization syntax

Comment: is this undefined behavior?

Comment: @0d0a: it can't be undefined behaviour if it doesn't even compile!

Comment: @0d0a: OK - my bad - I guess it compiles as C but not as C++.

Comment: @PaulR yes, question is tagged C, and thus may I repeat the question: so is this UB (in C)?

Comment: @0d0a: Treat warnings as errors. The diagnostic is mandatory.

Comment: @0d0a It does not compile. Use a real C compiler instead of that online thing, then compile it as C. `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. A pointer-to-pointer cannot be initialized with an array, nor can it be initialized with the pointer to the first element that they array decays into.

Comment: @Lundin this online thing uses same gcc that you reference in your advice, though -pedantic-errors make it impossible to compile, it is truth

Answer (score 3):

The first line is standard syntax for initializing an array of `char*`.

The second line is simply invalid, a type error.

See it live on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53464db7e2f31cfa

You can save it with a compound-literal though (C99):

```
char **c = (char*[]){ "str1", "str2", "str3", "str4" };
```

Beware that a non-constant compound-literal is in automatic-storage if defined in a function.

If you want it to be a constant literal (and thus in static storage), like the strings (which confusingly have type `char[]`), do it thus:

```
char **c = (char**)&*(const char* const []){ "str1", "str2", "str3", "str4" };
```

Comment: type-error, not syntax-error, ok. Still, open my coliru-link.

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to use compound literals for this, since it doesn't even make any sense to have a pointer-to-pointer in the first place.

Comment: @Lundin: depends on where, what and why. Though if you directly assign to a variable, probably. Cannot say so now, as there is absolutely no context why the OP asks his question.

Comment: +1, but you are wrong in one point, the storage class of a compound literal depends on its context. In file scope it is of static storage duration, and this then is a effective way to assign a non-trivial default value to a pointer.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Fixed. And that's one of the few places I would ever use it.